# using libavcodec to decode video to YUV422

Tags: ffmpeg, rgb, video-processing, yuv, libavcodec

I want to write a C++ application that opens a mp4 file and decode it as a yuv422 file.
I wrote some code based on libavcodec tutorial but I couldn't find the place to set the bit depth and the format to YUV422.

here is the some of the code i wrote

```
void read_video_stream(AVFormatContext *pFormatContext, AVCodec *pCodec, AVCodecParameters *pCodecParameters,
                       int video_stream_index)
{
    AVCodecContext *pCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
    std::unique_ptr<AVCodecContext, av_deleter> ctx_guard(pCodecContext);
    if (!pCodecContext) {
        return;
    }
    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(pCodecContext, pCodecParameters) < 0) {
        return;
    }
    // i tried setting it here
    if (avcodec_open2(pCodecContext, pCodec, NULL) < 0) {
        return;
    }
    while (true) {
        std::unique_ptr<AVPacket, std::function<void(AVPacket*)>> packet{
                        new AVPacket,
                        [](AVPacket* p){ av_packet_unref(p); delete p; }};

        av_init_packet(packet.get());
        int response = av_read_frame(pFormatContext, packet.get());
        if (AVERROR_EOF == response) {
            std::cout << "EOF\n";
        }
        else if (response < 0) {
            std::cout << "Error " << response;
            return;
        }
        if (packet->stream_index != video_stream_index) {
            continue;
        }
        response = avcodec_send_packet(pCodecContext, packet.get());
        if (response < 0) {
            std::cout << "Error while sending a packet to the decoder: " << response;
            return;
        }
        while (response >= 0) {
            std::shared_ptr<AVFrame> pFrame{  av_frame_alloc(), AVFrameDeleter};
            response = avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pFrame.get());
            if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (response == AVERROR_EOF) {
                std::cerr << "got to last frame\n";
                return;
            }
            else if (response < 0) {
                std::cerr << "Error while receiving a frame from the decoder: " << response;
                return;
            }

            if (response >= 0) {
                // copy line to cyclic buffer
                cb.push_back(std::move(pFrame));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

my end goal is to send the uncompressed data (need to be in pFrame->data[0-2]) to a device in the network.
can you please help me with this issue
thanks

Comment: You don’t decode to a spacific format. You decode to what ever format the stream was encoded to. If you want a different format, you convert (with swacale) after it’s decided.

Comment: Which specific format of uncompressed data does the *network device* expect?

Comment: y00cb00cr00y01,y02cb01cr01y03..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment says it all *"You don’t decode to a spacific format. You decode to what ever format the stream was encoded to. If you want a different format, you convert (with swacale) after it’s decided."*

I'll fill the gaps. Most majority of movie files (mp4) originally YUV420P format, so this is what you'll get after decoding. But this may be different to so I call it Decoded Pixel Format. After you get AVFrame with Decoded Pixel Format you can convert it to any other pixel format with `swscale()` function.

Pixel format conversion (with `swscale()`) requires two things:

1) Set up scaler context. In FFmpeg, pixel format conversion and scaling is done via same function. Keep the both sizes same and you'll get no scaling, just conversion.

You don't need to do this more than once unless the parameters changed and no longer valid:

```
SwsContext *swsContext = sws_getContext(src_width, src_height, src_pixfmt,
                                        dst_width, dst_height, dst_pixfmt,
                                        SWS_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Example `src_pixfmt` is `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P`
Example `dst_pixfmt` is `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV422P` or `AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422`
`SWS_BILINEAR` is the scaling algorithm. You may need this some point when scaling also needed. They say Bilinear is good for upscaling and Bicubic good for downscaling. I'm no expert in this field. But what I know is bilinear is works well and faster than many other algorithms.

2) And to do conversion you'll need something like this:

```
AVFrame *dstframe = av_frame_alloc();
if (dstframe == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: av_frame_alloc() failed.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

dstframe->format = AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422; /* choose same format set on sws_getContext() */
dstframe->width  = srcframe->width; /* must match sizes as on sws_getContext() */
dstframe->height = srcframe->height; /* must match sizes as on sws_getContext() */
int ret = av_frame_get_buffer(dstframe, 32);
if (ret < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not allocate the video frame data\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* do the conversion */
ret = sws_scale(swsContext,             /* SwsContext* on step (1) */
                srcframe->data,         /* srcSlice[] from decoded AVFrame */
                srcframe->linesize,     /* srcStride[] from decoded AVFrame */
                0,                      /* srcSliceY   */
                src_height,             /* srcSliceH  from decoded AVFrame */
                dstframe->data,         /* dst[]       */
                dstframe->linesize);    /* dstStride[] */

if (ret < 0)
{
    /* error handling */
}
```

After successful conversion you'll have what you want on `dstframe`.

Check more formats, details on functions and parameters here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/index.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, first thank, in the AVframe in the data and linesize i have three values 1920 960 and 960 (y,CB,CR). but i was expecting the get the entire frame not 1920.... do i have only one line or all the frame?

Comment: You'll get AVFrame which is entire frame this is what you asked. You'll see Y is in `AVFrame->data[0]`, U (CB?) is `data[1]` and V (CR) in `data[2]` with corresponding strides (`linesize[0..2]`) IF and ONLY IF it is a PLANAR format you converted. Packed formats have everything packed in `data[0]` (i.e. uyvy422).

Comment: is there a way to get the data in a packed of y00cb00cr00y01,y02cb01cr01y03...?

Comment: I think closest to what you asked is either `AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422` or `AV_PIX_FMT_YUYV422`. The question is if these are not what you asked and if you checked and cannot find suitable pixel format at https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixfmt_8h.html#a9a8e335cf3be472042bc9f0cf80cd4c5
So I can say what you're doing is either wrong or highly customized.
And anyway, you can always write your own manipulating function for any combination but again I never recommend this. Because most codecs (i.e. h264) will only accept a selection of known formats. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: a really customize layout i was asked to do

Comment: Hi, i wrote everything and it works for HD 1920*1080 stream.
But I have a problem with 4K 3840*2160, i get a core dump accessing data in the AVFrame
av_frame->data[2][1091 * av_frame->linesize[2]] // this carshes
av_frame->linesize[2] is 1920 and av_frame->height is 2160.
can you please help me understand why it crashes?

Comment: i think i understand the issue the 4K file is YUV420 not 422

Comment: Btw, for 4K content, yuv420p10 is common (10bit format). HEVC (h265) codecs expect that (yes also works with 8bit good old yuv420p).